# Main.js file causing the whole page to crash

Tags: javascript, html, opacity

I am making a multipage website. I add this preloader to my index page only. I don't get errors in index pages but get many errors on my other pages for this.

The errors i found:
main.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
Here :

```js
function loader(success) {
  document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';

  let time = window.onload;
  let obj = document.querySelector('.preLoader'),
    inner = document.querySelector('.preLoader .count');
  let w = 0,
    t = setInterval(function() {
      w = w + 1;
      inner.textContent = w + '%';
      if (w > 99) {
        obj.classList.add('loaded');
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
        clearInterval(t);
        w = 0;
        if (success) {
          return success(t);
        }
      }
    }, time);
}
loader();
```

```html
<!--    PRELOADER    -->
<div class="preLoader t_center g_center fixed" id="preLoader">
  <div class="count">%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You must be loading `main.js` in other files that don't have the preloader HTML.

Comment: just make sure you're on index before you run that piece of code.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `let time = window.onload`?

Comment: Or add a check around the rest of the code: `if (inner)`

Comment: let time = window.onload for preloader timing.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that your `inner` variable has been set to `null` instead of the reference to the `<div>` element that you are expecting.  This happens when `document.querySelector('.preLoader .count')` doesn't match anything, which will be the case on the web pages where you don't include your preloader.

You can avoid the problem by checking the value of `inner` is not `null` before you use it:

```
if (inner) {
    inner.textContent = w + '%';
}
```